# Making a Login screen similar to the lock screen

Tags: ios, swift, uitextfield

Im trying to make a login screen similar to the lock screen with 4 textField.
The problem i'm facing is with changing the focus from one text field to the next.

- when i say `secondTextField.becomeFirstResponder()`, the value of the firstTextField gets copied to the secondTextField
- i'm using a decimal pad - keyboard type

Here is what i have done so far and i can't find a way around to fix the problem :

- Using UITextFieldDelegate
- made IBOutlet connection for all the textField
- `firstText.delegate = self
   secondText.delegate = self
    thirdText.delegate = self
  firstText.becomeFirstResponder()`
- func textField(textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersInRange range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {
      var newLength = countElements(textField.text) + countElements(string) - range.length

  ```
      if newLength == 1 {
          if textField == firstText{
              changeFocus(textField)
          }else if textField == secondText {
              changeFocus(textField)
          }else if textField == thirdText {
              changeFocus(textField)
          }

      }
  return newLength <= 1
  ```

  }

  func changeFocus(nextFocus: UITextField){

  ```
  if nextFocus == firstText {
      firstText.resignFirstResponder()
      secondText.becomeFirstResponder()
  } else if nextFocus == secondText {
      secondText.resignFirstResponder()
      thirdText.becomeFirstResponder()
  } else if nextFocus == thirdText {
      thirdText.resignFirstResponder()
  }
  ```

  }

How can i do this correctly, any help and suggestion please.

Comment: use this https://github.com/kylef/BSKeyboardControls

Comment: Would be great if i can do these without a library.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found something similar here: [similar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2129593/uitextfield-automatically-move-to-next-after-1-character)

Got it to work, with two limitations :

- Firstly, I cant delete backwards
- Second, the user has to tap on the first textField if the passCode is wrong.
  But for now these is good enough.
- Here are the methods

  ```
  func textField(textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersInRange range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {

  var shouldProcess = false
  var moveToNextTextField = false
  var insertStringLength = countElements(string)
  if insertStringLength == 0 {
      shouldProcess = true
  }
  else {
      if countElements(textField.text) == 0 {
          shouldProcess = true
      }
  }
  if shouldProcess {
     var myString = textField.text
      if countElements(myString) == 0{
          myString = myString + string

          password = password + myString
          moveToNextTextField = true
      }
      textField.text = myString

      if moveToNextTextField {
          changeFocus(textField)
      }
  }
  return false
  }
  ```
- method to change the focus :

  ```
  func changeFocus(nextTextField : UITextField){
  if  nextTextField == firstText {
      firstText.resignFirstResponder()
      secondText.becomeFirstResponder()
  } else if nextTextField == secondText {
      secondText.resignFirstResponder()
      thirdText.becomeFirstResponder()
  } else if nextTextField == thirdText {
      thirdText.resignFirstResponder()
      fourthText.becomeFirstResponder()
  } else if nextTextField == fourthText {
      fourthText.resignFirstResponder()
  }
  ```

  }
- Method to check the pin/passcode :

  ```
  func textFieldShouldEndEditing(textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
  if textField == fourthText {
     thirdText.resignFirstResponder()
      let pass = defaultUser.stringForKey(Admin)
      println("password = \(password)")
      if pass  == password {

          println("the password is correct")
          dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) { () -> Void in
              self.performSegueWithIdentifier("SegueToSecond", sender: self)
          }

      } else {
          println("wrong password")
          thirdText.text = ""
          secondText.text = ""
          firstText.text = ""
          fourthText.text = ""
          password = ""
          view.reloadInputViews()
      }

  }

  return true
  }
  ```

Hope these help some one later on.

Comment: For anyone out there finding this answer, you can deal with the not being able to delete problem by replacing `return false` of the `shouldChangeCharactersInRange` with `return (count(myString) - range.length < 1)`

Answer (score 0):

Use this delegate method to change the focus

```
func textFieldShouldReturn(textField: UITextField) -> Bool
```

Comment: a decimal pad does not have a return or done button, so the delegate method never gets called. I have tried with textFieldShouldEndEditing method as well.

Comment: If so then try to check the below link :http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26031798/how-to-get-keyboard-location-in-ios-8-add-done-button-on-numberpad. U need to add the return button to the keyboard for ur desire requirement

Comment: is there any way around where i don't have to use the return button? really want to keep the ui to default, so i don't have to change the keyboard.

Comment: To do this u need one extra button. I would suggest u can add one button in the background of the UI. Which u can use to change the focus.

Comment: Otherwise instead of NumberPad use Number and Punctuation keyboard. restrict the Other symbols. It has the return button

Comment: appreciate the suggestion. But when you put it practically, the User experience get reduced if he has to tab a button each time to input the next pin.

Comment: Yes but to change the focus he need to tap on return/other button na??

Comment: i'm able to change the focus, the problem is the textfield is not empty when it gets the focus. it holds the value of the previous textField. I need to find a way to give an empty second text field when it gets the focus.

Answer (score 0):

To add a little more to **svrushal** answer:

```
func textFieldShouldReturn(textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
   if textField == firstText {
       secondText.becomeFirstResponder()
   }

   if textField == secondText {
       thirdText.becomeFirstResponder()
   }

   if textField == thirdText {
       fourthText.becomeFirstResponder()
   }

}
```

Comment: Have tried this, but the delegate method never gets called, like i said i'm using a decimal pad, so i'm not sure this method woks here.

Comment: oh ok! Sorry i didn`t notice

Answer (score 0):

you can refer this link https://github.com/dhennessy/PAPasscode/blob/master/PAPasscode/PAPasscodeViewController.h

it will help you out.